# Shell: Determine if file exists on another server true or false

Tags: shell

I have an if statement I use to find if a file exists on another server. While testing with the file not on the other server it is returning true which suggests it is only looking on the current server even though I have used ssh to connect to the other server.

```
if [ 'ssh $USER@$IP_ADDRESS test -e -name "$IPADDRESS:$DIRECTORY/$FILE"' ];
```

Is there anyway that I can get this to work within the `if` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to test again result returned by ssh, so no need in `[]`.

ssh will return 0 (True) if remote `test` succeeded, so:

```
if `ssh $USER@$IP_ADDRESS test -e -name "$IPADDRESS:$DIRECTORY/$FILE"`; then
    # do something if True
fi
```